# use of `cons` inside apply mapcar

Tags: common-lisp

In the Lisp Koans, the following form is used [here](https://github.com/google/lisp-koans/blob/master/koans/mapcar-and-reduce.lsp#L37) to transpose a matrix:

`(defun transpose (L) (apply #'mapcar (cons #'list L)))`

As I parse this function, `(cons #'list L)` returns a list `'(#'list L1 L2 L3 ...)`, where `L_i` are the columns of the matrix `L`. Then `apply` unfolds the list, and now `mapcar list` has as its argument the columns of `L` as lists, which constructs the rows of `L`.

I wonder whether there is any reason, besides the didactic one of forcing a new Lisp student to remember and understand the usage of `cons`, to not simply write

`(defun transpose (L) (apply #'mapcar #'list L))`

since `L` is already a list (of columns (as lists)), `apply` will prepend `#'list` to the lists in `L` before unpacking them.

Can this be simplified any more? I think the `apply` is necessary in order to unpack the arguments in order to use `mapcar` to create lists out of the rows, but I'm new to functional programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Lisp Koans were written by Maclisp programmers, long before Common Lisp existed. In Maclisp, `APPLY` just took two arguments, a function and a list of arguments. Common Lisp generalized this, to allow the syntax you use. But in Maclisp you had to call `CONS` or `LIST*` explicitly.